# Allow REST api access only by personal webiste (not other requests servcices)

Tags: django, ajax, cors, backend, csrf

I know this question was asked before but I didn't found a feasible solution for my problem, I implemented **CORS** inside my Django application in order to restrict the domain access and also used **CSRF** tokens for secure data transfer against unsecured HTTP methods, **but still I can make requests to an API via postman or other HTTP services, how can I avoid that?**

**NOTE:**
my app **doesn't make use of users with oAuth system** and more, it makes a POST request to the database in order to get a token (app term specific) regardless of the person who is making the request, but **I want only my website to make such request and NO MORE**, how to do that?

Comment: Can you share the code that you're having problem? It can be your views.py for example.

Comment: If you're sending requests from your website's backend, I suggest you use a secure token, I mean create a secure token that belongs to your website and send it to the API per each request. 
If you're sending requests from your website's frontend, It's probably impossible to avoid unwanted requests.
Also, you can use firewall rules to restrict the request origins.

Comment: This is CORS, you don't need to do anything about it, it works by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Cross-origin resource sharing **(CORS)** is a mechanism that allows restricted resources on a web page to be requested from another domain outside the domain from which the first resource was served.

You can think of **CORS** as a standard that works in the background of your front-end requests that is **enforced only by web browsers**. So if you want to request with an HTTP client that is not a browser, `curl` for instance, you won't go through the CORS validation thing at all.

So bottom line:
If you want to prevent other non-browser HTTP clients from making requests to your APIs you need to think of a solution on your own.

for instance:

Create a [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/middleware/) that checks if incoming requests are originated from a list of trusted origins you have in your app settings.